# Android API 16 option menu doesn't show .but show menu in android version API 10

Tags: java, android, menu

> The results are as follows
>
> 1. htc desire s 2.3.3 : work
> 2. htc sensation 4.0.3 : work
> 3. emulator 3.2 :not work
> 4. galaxy tab 2 10.1 :not work

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case utility.SETTING_ID:
            Intent intentsetting = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    actPreferences.class);
            intentsetting.putExtra("Menu", utility.SETTING_ID);
            startActivity(intentsetting);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, utility.SETTING_ID, 0, getApplicationContext(),
                getResources().getString(R.string.txt_setting)).setIcon(
                R.drawable.setting);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing targetSdkVersion to 8. It should fix it. Newer api's don't support menu button as the older ones did.

Comment: minSdkVersion 8 worked for me as well. Accept my answer if I helped you, please.